# Why using batch to predict when applying Batch Normalization is cheating?

Tags: deep-learning, batch-normalization

In a [post](https://www.quora.com/How-does-batch-normalization-behave-differently-at-training-time-and-test-time) on Quora, someone says

> At test time, the layer is supposed to see only one test data point at
>   a time, hence computing the mean / variance along a whole batch is
>   infeasible (and is cheating).

But as long as testing data have not been seen by the network during training isn't it ok to use several testing images?

I mean, our network as been train to predict using batches, so what is the issue with giving it batches?

If someone could explain what informations our network gets from batches that it is not suppose to have that would be great.